# Is the function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x):=\dfrac {x-(a+b)/2}{(x-a)(b-x)} , \forall x \in (a,b)$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Is the function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x):=\dfrac {x-\dfrac{a+b}{2}}{(x-a)(b-x)} , \forall x \in (a,b)$$ a homeomorphism ?

I have noticed that it is continuous and also noticed that it is surjective as $\lim_{x \to a+} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to b-} f(x)=+\infty$ ; but I am not sure whether it is injective or not and even if it is injective , whether the inverse is continuous or not . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: You might this easier to see if you write it as the composition of two functions: homeomorphisms $(a,b) \to (-1,1)$ and $(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Try computing the derivative, if I didn't make a mistake the result is always positive.

Comment: Regarding the openness: Every injective continuous function from an open set $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is an open map. This is a special case of [Invariance of Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), but a direct proof is possible, using the fact that injective maps are strictly monotonic.